# While Passing a MediaStream object through Ajax to PHP, Ajax call returns a blank object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a MediaStream object through Ajax to PHP and simply just returning that object. But it returns a blank object. Please find the code as below.

**jQuery Code:**
globStream contains the media stream Object.

```
globStream = new Array(globStream);
formData.delete("stream");
formData.append("stream", JSON.stringify(globStream));
                
$.ajax({
         url         :   "/editpeople",
         dataType    :   "text",
         type        :   "POST",
         cache       :   false,
         contentType :   false,
         processData :   false,
         data        :   formData,
         success     :   function(result) {
             result = JSON.parse(result.trim())[0];
         },
         error       :   function(jqXHR, exception) {
         }
});
```

**PHP Code:**

```
$mediaSream = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST["stream"]));
$returnCode = json_encode($mediaSream);
echo $returnCode;
```

The result I am receiving is as shown in the screen print attached.
[image: MediaStream_object_before_and_after_Ajax_call]